# How to append lists to an empty list to get a list of lists?

Tags: python

Yes, this question has been addressed many times here, but I can't find a solution to my specific use case.

I have a function that hands back a tuple of latitude/longitude coordinates.  I'd like to:

1. prepend a city name to this tuple
2. create a list out of #1
3. append this list to an empty list
4. repeat for each time the function is run

For example:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = 'MyApp')

cities_list = ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Houston']

for city in cities_list:
    
    temp_list = []
    
    city_coordinates = geolocator.geocode(city)
    
    latitude = city_coordinates.latitude
    longitude = city_coordinates.longitude
    
    list_element = list(city, latitude, longitude)
       
    temp_list.append(list_element)

temp_list

TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

This is what I'd like `temp_list` to look like:

```
[['New York', 40.7127281, -74.0060152], ['Los Angeles', 34.0536909, -118.242766], ['Houston', 29.7589382, -95.3676974]]
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you need each element to be a list? A short sequence of items, each one identified by its position, would be more idiomatic as a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not your direct question, you are building a list by consistently appending to an empty list. Nothing really bad but it is not the Pythonic way. It is more efficient (hence more *Pythonic*) to build the list as a comprehension:

```
temp_list = [ [city] + list(geolocator.geocode(city)) for city in cities_list]
```

or even better (thank to juanpa.arrivillaga):

```
temp_list = [ [city, *geolocator.geocode(city)] for city in cities_list]
```

It is not always possible but it is here, because you can convert a tuple into a list with `list` and concatenate two lists with `+`.

Comment: "Even if it is not your direct question, you are building a list by consistently appending to an empty list. Nothing really bad but it is not the Pythonic way. It is more efficient (hence more Pythonic) to build the list as a comprehension:" I disagree with this. Using `.append` in a loop is a perfectly pythonic way to create a list, list comprehensions are a construct that can be more readable, but it isn't really more efficient. There are some micro-optimizations, but a large chunk of that can be replicated by simply caching the method resolution, e.g. `append = mylist.append`.

Comment: Also, I would do `[city, *gelolocator.geocode(city)]`

Comment: Can you be sure that `geolocator.geocode(city)` is returning a tuple?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I do agree with you and I have improved my answer with you second comment. But I have just tried to build a list from a range and use timeit on it. Result: appending takes twice the time of a comprehension which in turn takes twice the time of `list(range(n))` (for n = 2048).

Comment: @surge10: I am not. I blindly trusted OP on that part...

Comment: @SergeBallesta well he added the city to a fake tuple he created if you read this code `list_element = list(city, latitude, longitude)` which is actually an object initialisation code. And I am doubtful is the function returns a named tuple or a dataclass.

Comment: @SergeBallesta well, yes, because if you don't do anything in the mapping part, then the advantages of a list comprehension (with the special `LIST_APPEND` op code) are the most significant (because the difference is a specialized op-code versus a method resolution followed by a method call, both relatively expensive operations). Add a little work to it, like `x*x + 32` and the difference narrows considerably (almost disappears)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is not right.

```py
temp_list = []

for city in cities_list:
    
    city_coordinates = geolocator.geocode(city)
    
    latitude = city_coordinates.latitude
    longitude = city_coordinates.longitude
    temp_list.append([city, latitude, longitude])
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
list_element = list(city, latitude, longitude)
```

could simply be

```
list_element = [city, latitude, longitude]
```

Otherwise to initialize a list you'd need a single iterable, for example passing a tuple

```
list_element = list((city, latitude, longitude))
```

but at that point it is more idiomatic to just construct using the literal list syntax from above.

Comment: Thank you, @Cory Kramer.  Strangely, this gives me back **only the last element** (Houston).

Comment: @zeroes_ones That is because you should move this initialization `temp_list = []` outside of your for loop

Comment: @CoryKramer could is not the right word. Doing what he/she did gives an error.